# Angular 11 update child component from nested child

Tags: angular, components, parent-child, angular-reactive-forms, eventemitter

I have a component that looks like this:

1 Parent component containing multiple (nested) child components.

`ParentComponentForm`->`UserDetailsFormComponent`->`GeneraldetailsComponent`
`ParentComponentForm`->`FormProgressComponent`

I want to update the `FormProgressComponent` once certain values are set in the `GeneralDetailsComponent`.
I tried working with nested `EventEmitter`s but the component won't update.

How can I update the `FormProgressComponent` values from my `GeneralDetailsComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

Try having your data in a Service and inject the service into both components. This will allow you to update data in centralized location due to the singleton nature of services in Angular.

Do all your updates through the service as well